# How to find dependency conflicts in 3rd party libraries

Tags: java, dependencies, maven-3, coursier

I'm looking for a way to find dependency conflicts in 3rd party libraries. I'm aware of `mvn dependency:tree`, its `-Dverbose` and `-Dincludes` options. This works well but has a couple of drawbacks:

- I need to set up a `pom.xml` file with the 3rd party dependency. This is a somewhat roundabout way and tedious for quickly looking through the dependencies of a couple of libraries.
- `dependency:tree` downloads all dependencies, which can be slow and consume a lot of bandwidth for large dependency graphs.
- `dependency:tree -Dverbose` does show conflicts but it is quite verbose as it also shows all non conflicting dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CLI of the [Coursier](https://get-coursier.io/) dependency resolver can do this. E.g. to find dependency conflicts in `com.bynder:bynder-java-sdk:2.2.8` you can use Coursier's `resolve` command with the `--conflict` flag:

```
$ cs resolve --conflicts   com.bynder:bynder-java-sdk:2.2.8 

org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.4.10 was selected, but
  com.squareup.okio:okio:2.8.0 wanted version 1.4.0

io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.20 was selected, but
  com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.9.0 wanted version 2.0.0

com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0 was selected, but
  com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0 wanted version 3.14.9

org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.10 was selected, but
  com.squareup.okio:okio:2.8.0 wanted version 1.4.0
```

This outputs a list of conflicts and nothing more. No artifacts are downloaded besides its metadata and the whole process is very quick.

To further explore where the conflict on e.g. `com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp` is coming from, you can run

```
$ cs resolve com.bynder:bynder-java-sdk:2.2.8 --what-depends-on com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp
  Result:
└─ com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0
   ├─ com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.0
   │  └─ com.bynder:bynder-java-sdk:2.2.8
   └─ com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0 com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.9 -> 4.9.0
      ├─ com.bynder:bynder-java-sdk:2.2.8
      ├─ com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.9.0
      │  └─ com.bynder:bynder-java-sdk:2.2.8
      └─ com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0
         └─ com.bynder:bynder-java-sdk:2.2.8
```

The output is an inverse dependency tree showing all subtrees that depend on `com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp`.